# Update a time field dynamically when checking a checkbox in Rails & dynamically updating the DB without using a Submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm trying to do the following:

1) When a checkbox gets checked, I want the `Time of Arrival` box to be updated with the time when the checkbox got checked dynamically.
I don't want to be pressing a submit button or anything of that sort, it should be dynamic, via AJAX i guess.
[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
     <td><b>Present</b></td>
     <td><b>Student ID</b></td>
     <td><b>First Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Time of Arrival</b></td>
    </tr>
<% @register.student_registers.each do |student_register| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "student_registers_ids[#{student_register.id}]",  student_register.id, student_register.present?%></td>
      <td><%= student_register.student.university_id%></td>
      <td><%= student_register.student.first_name.titlecase%></td>
      <td><%= student_register.student.last_name.titlecase%></td>
      <td><%= student_register.time_of_arrival %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

2) The other thing I want to do is to update the record in the database, as soon as the `Present` checkbox gets checked, without having to press a `Submit` button. This will be done in the `model#show` page, not the `model#edit` page.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I changed the code around, but it still isn't working...

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
     <td><b>Present</b></td>
     <td><b>Student ID</b></td>
     <td><b>First Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Time of Arrival</b></td>
    </tr>
  <% form_tag :remote => true %>
<% @register.student_registers.each do |student_register| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "student_registers_ids[#{student_register.id}]",
                            student_register.id, student_register.present?,
                            :disabled => false,
                            :onclick => 'popup  ' %></td>
      <td><%= label_tag 'UniversityId', student_register.student.university_id%></td>
      <td><%= label_tag 'FirstName', student_register.student.first_name.titlecase%></td>
      <td><%= label_tag 'LastName', student_register.student.last_name.titlecase%></td>
      <td><%= label_tag student_register.time_of_arrival, nil, :class => 'TimeOfArrival'%>    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
<%= submit_tag "Save", :confirm => "You sure", :onclick => 'alert("Test")'%>
```

Please, anybody help....

Comment: For part 2, I tried using `<% simple_form_for @register, :remote => true do |f| %>` but that didn't help. For part 1, I haven't tried, as I'm not sure how to implement the AJAX or JS/JQuery in Rails

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Designate a common CSS class for all the checkbox inputs (to be used as a jQuery selector later).
2. Create an empty `<span>...</span>` element with an id that encodes the student id (e.g., `'toa_1234'`) in the "Time of arrival" cell.
3. Use jQuery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the message to the server.
4. Create a corresponding controller or action to process the AJAX POST and return the recorded (server-side) time.
5. On AJAX success, display the recorded server time *and* disable the checkbox (so it can't be clicked again).

HTML/ERB:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "student_registers_ids[#{student_register.id}]",
  student_register.id, false,
  :class => 'student_present' %></td>
<td><%= student_register.student.university_id%></td>
<td><%= student_register.student.first_name.titlecase%></td>
<td><%= student_register.student.last_name.titlecase%></td>
<td><%= content_tag :span, student_register.time_of_arrival,
  :id => "toa_#{student_register.student.id}" %></td>
```

JS/CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  $('input[type="checkbox"].student_present').change (e) ->
    checkbox = $(this)
    student_id = checkbox.val()
    $.ajax
      url: '/register/present'
      method: 'POST'
      dataType: 'json'
      data:
        student_id: student_id
      success: (data) ->
        $("span#toa_#{student_id}").html(data['toa'])
        checkbox.attr 'disabled', true
```

Controller/action:

```
def present
  student_id = params['student_id']
  # TODO: mark student present and save in database
  recorded_toa = Time.now # TODO replace with actual time
  render json: { student_id: student_id, toa: recorded_toa.strftime('%I:%M %P') }
end
```

Comment: Hey @AlistarIsrael, if I'm correct, do I just plug the code into my application, and it should work? Because currently when I do so, neither the time_of_arrival field gets updated, nor does it save the record in the DB

Comment: @teenOmar The code won't work for you _as is_. You have to adapt the code to your particular app. What I've presented is merely a working skeleton or template showing to use jQuery to send some data to an action on the server and get some data back. (Also, see a slight correction I just made on the JS/CoffeeScript code.)

Comment: Not even the appearance of the `time_of_arrival`? What exactly would i have to do. in order to adapt it and get it to work in my app?

Comment: You need to do those things marked `# TODO:`. You need to figure that out yourself, given your data model and specific ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: So it's just the `TODO` parts which require my own models and data? So if my model is `Student`, the time of arrival would be `Register.first.student_register.first.students.first.time_of_arrival` for instance, and this is how i would set it??

Comment: Hey @AlistairIsrael, I tried using your code and adding my own code to the `TODO`, but to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: The only thing I didn't put is that you have to add the corresponding route to your controller/action in `routes.rb`. In my example, it'd be something like `post 'register/present' => 'register#present', format: :json`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26234/discussion-between-teenomar-and-alistairisrael)